# How to convert string into a dict escaping special characters in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.x

I'm trying to convert the following string into a dictionary, where IP becomes a key, and everything else after | becomes a value:

```
my_string = '''10.11.22.33|{"property1": "0",     "property2": "1", "property3":     "1", "property4": "1", "property5": "0"}
10.11.22.34|{"property1": "0",     "property2": "0", "property3":     "1", "property4": "1", "property5": "0", "property6": "0", "property7": "1", "property8": "0", "property9": "0", "property10": "1"}'''
```

This is the code I tried:

```
d = dict(node.split('|') for node in my_string.split())
```

However, I get this error:

```
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #1 has length 1; 2 is required
```

So I simplified my_string to just one line:

```
my_string = '10.11.22.33|{"property1": "0",     "property2": "1", "property3":     "1", "property4": "1", "property5": "0"}'
```

And used this code to first split the line:

```
wow = my_string.split('|')
```

output:

```
['10.11.22.33', '{"property1": "0",     "property2": "1", "property3":     "1", "property4": "1", "property5": "0"}']
```

The above is a list of two elements.  However, when I try to create dictionary out of it, it fails with this error:

```
d = dict(wow)
```

output:

```
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 11; 2 is required
```

I do not want to modify the value - it needs to be preserved as is.  What is the proper way to get this line into a dictionary so that it looks like this:

```
{'10.11.22.33': '{"property1": "0",     "property2": "1", "property3":     "1", "property4": "1", "property5": "0"}'}
```

This is Python 2.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first approach is correct except that it splits at the wrong places because [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) uses whitespace as the separator character by default. Try [`str.splitlines()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines) instead:

```
d = dict(node.split('|') for node in my_string.splitlines())
```

Comment: This works and is simple.  Read somewhere that split was splitting on new line characters...  Must have been dreaming.  Guess it's time to take a break.

Answer (score 2):

You need to `split` your string on `\n` first:

```
dict(ip.split('|') for ip in s.split('\n'))
```

Also you can take a look into [**`re.findall`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall):

```
dict(re.findall(r'(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+\d+).*?(\{.*?\})', s))
```

Where `s` is your string

Comment: Not splitting on new line was the issue.

Comment: what was the issue? according to your comment it was the issue

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear - the issue was that I was not splitting on new line.

Comment: and i did it in my answer

Comment: I believe I can only pick one solution as answering the question.  I prefer the solution with splitlines rather, than with \n, as it's platform independent.  However, I marked your answer as useful.